# Typhoeus doesn't return to response body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, typhoeus

I have a hydra requests that works well in development. But fails in production. Response looks like this

```
options:
  :return_code: :ok
  :response_headers: ! "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\nTransfer-Encoding:
    chunked\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nStatus: 200\r\nX-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger
    (mod_rails/mod_rack) 3.0.19\r\nX-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1\r\nETag: \"2ef0bc08f9b4fa4c7ecc4092f387c4c7\"\r\nCache-Control:
    max-age=0, private, must-revalidate\r\nX-Request-Id: df304fd28b406f8b3a97c84a7ce4de5e\r\nX-Runtime:
    0.614748\r\nDate: Sat, 27 Jul 2013 08:03:09 GMT\r\nX-Rack-Cache: invalidate, pass\r\nServer:
    nginx/1.2.6 + Phusion Passenger 3.0.19\r\n\r\n"
  :response_body: ! '{"status":"success","message":"Message Sent","code":"200"}'
  :httpauth_avail: 0
  :total_time: 5.700828
  :starttransfer_time: 5.700666
  :appconnect_time: 4.387121
  :pretransfer_time: 4.387193
  :connect_time: 0.446846
  :namelookup_time: 0.001348
  :effective_url: !binary |-
    aHR0cHM6Ly9maXJlZmx5YXBpLmNvbS9hcGkvc21z
  :primary_ip: !binary |-
    MTczLjI0Ni40MC4yNA==
  :response_code: 200
```

But in production it returns a `ssl_cacert` code:

```
options:
  :return_code: :ssl_cacert
  :response_headers: ''
  :response_body: ''
  :httpauth_avail: 0
  :total_time: 0.419993
  :starttransfer_time: 0.0
  :appconnect_time: 0.0
  :pretransfer_time: 0.0
  :connect_time: 0.321081
  :namelookup_time: 0.245361
  :effective_url: !binary |-
    aHR0cHM6Ly9maXJlZmx5YXBpLmNvbS9hcGkvc21z
  :primary_ip: !binary |-
    MTczLjI0Ni40MC4yNA==
  :response_code: 0
```

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by adding the below to the typhoeus request:

```
ssl_verifypeer: false
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: That's a terrible advice to give. That opens SSL for a man in the middle attack.

Comment: This is not a fix, it's at best a workaround, and applying it without understanding its implications is dangerous.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same problem

While `ssl_verifypeer: false` works fine, 
I installed `libcurl4-openssl-dev` on my machine (Ubuntu) and now it verifies the certificates just fine without using setting verifypeer to false